# Duplication of Table View Elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

Hi I realize that this question has been asked before. I tried the previous solutions however to no avail unfortunately. What I am trying to do is to get my UISwitch to appear and not duplicate itself when scrolling on the table view. This is my current attempt however the UISwitch is not being displayed at all. Any help as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RestaurantCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    Restaurant *restaurant = [restaurants objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UISwitch *notificationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 15, 79, 27)];
    [notificationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:notificationSwitch];

    cell.textLabel.text = restaurant.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = restaurant.hours;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I am trying to do is to get my UISwitch to appear and not duplicate itself when scrolling on the table view

It seems you want one `UISwitch` to appear in all of the cells.
To address this issue, instead of creating the object in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you should move this code into `-viewDidLoad` and simply put this object on the resusable cells later.

---

Basically...
This should be in your `-viewDidLoad`:

```
//IMPORTANT: declare "UISwitch *notificationSwitch;" in the .h of this class
notificationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(245, 15, 79, 27)];
[notificationSwitch addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(switchChanged:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

and only this should be left in your `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:notificationSwitch];
```

---

thus we create the object just once and add the same object to the cell multiple times instead of creating multiple objects in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` (*that only look the same but are infact different objects*)

---

*PS: I have assumed that your delegate and datasource are hooked up properly, i.e. the execution flow does reach`-cellForRowAtIndexPath`*

Answer (score 0):

**Try to use this code instead of my static text you will put your text.It is working for me!**

[You can see the structure of cell Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smhRe.png)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifer";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1  reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }

    UISwitch *notificationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 5, 79, 27)];
    [notificationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:notificationSwitch];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"text label %d",indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"detail label %d",indexPath.row] ;
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: how can i go about that please? I am new to this! sorry :(